# Python/PyGame Select a Random Boolean From List

Tags: python, boolean, pygame, minesweeper

Python version: 2.7.8

Objective:  Making a Minesweeper game (trying to at least) on python with the PyGame library.

The Code:

```
import pygame, random, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
width, height = 400, 400
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
DRAWSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Matt's Minesweeper")
background = pygame.Surface(DRAWSURF.get_size())
background.fill((255, 255, 255))
DRAWSURF.blit(background, (0, 0))
pygame.display.flip()
board = []


class Square():
    isMine = None

    val = 0
    count = 0

    def draw(self):
        BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
        val = self.val
        count = self.count
        x = 100 + val * 60
        y = 0 + 60 * count
        pygame.draw.rect(DRAWSURF, BLACK, (x, y, 60, 60), 5)
        return self.isMine



class DrawBoard():

    def draw(self, grid):
        item = Square()
        for i in range(0, grid):
            item.val = i
            select = item.draw()
            board.append(select)
            for j in range(grid):
                item.count = j
                select_2 = item.draw()
                board.append(select_2)

class MineSet():
    temp = Square()
    def mineSet(self, mines):
        temp = self.temp
        for i in range(0, mines):
            test = random.choice(board)




while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    clock.tick(30)

    # Insert drawings here
    game = DrawBoard()
    game.draw(5)
    print board
    pygame.display.update()
```

The Issue: I have each individual square as its own object, as seen in class Square().  In the draw function of the Square class it returns a boolean of None (variable isMine) and when I call it later in the DrawBoard class it appends the object to the list 'board'.  To assign the mines for the game, I want to randomly select one of the Square objects created and change the boolean from None to True.   Maybe this isn't the best way to assign mines, but I'm trying to do my best.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: so you have a list of booleans and want to select one randomly?

Comment: might be easier just to create a dict mapping positions as keys to whether the mine has exploded or not as boolean values

Comment: You also never use `temp` or `test` in MineSet

Comment: I have a list of booleans that I need to randomly select a certain number of (mines parameter) and replace it with a different value

Comment: what is `select = item.draw()` supposed to do? The method returns nothing(so None by default) so you are setting select to None

Comment: Code is messy from countless tests @Padraid Cunningham

Comment: Thought I needed to assign to a variable so that I could append to the list.

Comment: You can append whatever you want to the list directly. I still think a global dict where you randomly set square positions to True will be a lot easier

Comment: `board = {(i,j):False for i in range(grid) for j in range(grid)}`

Comment: That's a lot better for storing locations and boolean values.. now how to randomly select them..?  Sorry for lack of understanding

Comment: how many do you want to set to True?

Comment: I was trying to use a method in the MineSet class to be able to be flexible with number of mines.

Comment: @Adam, I added an answer, I will explain exactly what is happening in a few minutes, basically you pass grid size and how many mines to set and use sample to randomly set to True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 from collections import OrderedDict
 from random import sample

class Square():
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 0
        self.count = 0
    def draw(self):
        BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
        x = 100 + self.val * 60
        y = 0 + 60 * self.count
        pygame.draw.rect(DRAWSURF, BLACK, (x, y, 60, 60), 5)


class DrawBoard():
    def __init__(self, grid, mines): # size of grid and how many mines to set
        self.grid_size = grid
        # create x,y coordinates and set all mains to False initially
        self.board = OrderedDict(((i,j),False) for i in range(grid) for j in range(grid))      
        self.mines = mines
        # pick random coords to place mines
        samp = sample(list(self.board),self.mines)
        for k in samp:
            self.board[k]=True
    def draw(self):
        item = Square()
        for i, j in self.board:
            item.val, item.count = i,j
            item.draw()

game = DrawBoard(5,5) # create board
game.draw() # draw

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    clock.tick(30)
   # game logic goes here
    pygame.display.update()
```

This should get you started, you need to let the user know when they are near a mine and handle how/when they win:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
width, height = 40, 40
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
DRAWSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Matt's Minesweeper")
background = pygame.Surface(DRAWSURF.get_size())
DRAWSURF.blit(background, (0, 0))
pygame.display.flip()
size = [255, 255]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

margin = 5

from collections import OrderedDict
from random import sample


class DrawBoard():
    def __init__(self, grid, mines):
        self.grid_size = grid
        self.board = OrderedDict(((i, j), False) for i in range(grid) for j in range(grid))
        self.mines = mines
        samp = sample(list(self.board), self.mines)
        for k in samp:
            self.board[k] = True

    def draw(self):
        for i, j in self.board:
            x = 100 + i * 60
            y = 0 + 60 * j
            pygame.draw.rect(DRAWSURF,(0,0,0), (x, y, 60, 60), margin)


game = DrawBoard(5, 5)
game.draw()


def game_over():
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 50)
    text = font.render('Game over!', True, (255, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255))
    text_rect = text.get_rect()
    text_rect.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
    text_rect.centery = screen.get_rect().centery
    screen.blit(text, text_rect)
    pygame.display.update()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()


user_won = False
user_lost = False

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # get mouse pos 
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            # change to grid coordinates
            column = pos[0] // (width + margin)
            row = pos[1] // (height + margin)
            print(game.board[row, column])
            if game.board[row, column]:
                user_lost = True
            else:
                game.board[row, column] = "picked"

    if user_lost:
        game_over()

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for row, column in game.board:
        color = (255, 255, 255)
        if game.board[row, column] == "picked":
            color = (0, 255, 0)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,
                         color,
                         [(margin + width) * column + margin,
                          (margin + height) * row + margin,
                          width,
                          height])

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

just generate a random value between `0` and `len(list)`. Then you can access the value using this syntax: `list[random_val]`
If you want to change a value: `list[random_val] = True`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a "tutorial" going over an implementation of the program, you can check out this [MineSweep recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577365/) on ActiveState's Python Cookbook. Version 2 of the code introduces the methods `__push` and `__build_mines` to handle the creation of the individual mines.